# Repeater with multible <textbox> with same ID, how to get the different ones?

Tags: .net

When the document loads I have a repeater with creates a couple of textfields wich in the webform have this code:

```
<input type="text" id="datafieldControllersHolder" name='datafieldControllersHolder_<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "datafieldid").ToString()%>' value='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "controllers").ToString()%>' runat="server" />
```

The problem I'm having is that inside the repeater this textfield gets generated a couple of times but I don't know how to access them when I do a PostBack.

With the testpage I'm working on right now I get two of those textfield wich looks like:

```
<input name="ctl00$ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ContentPlaceHolder3$datafieldsRepeater$ctl00$datafieldControllersHolder" type="text" id="ContentPlaceHolder1_ContentPlaceHolder3_datafieldsRepeater_datafieldControllersHolder_0" value=";1;2;3;4;5;6">
```

And

```
<input name="ctl00$ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ContentPlaceHolder3$datafieldsRepeater$ctl01$datafieldControllersHolder" type="text" id="ContentPlaceHolder1_ContentPlaceHolder3_datafieldsRepeater_datafieldControllersHolder_1" value=";7;8">
```

When I do the PostBack I know that I got two textfields and I also have the "datafieldid" that is used in the Name of the textfield.

But how do I use all this to access them? I have tried "Request.Form["datafieldControllersHolder_1"]" and "Request.Form["datafieldControllersHolder_2"]" but that didn't work.

If I need to use the FindControl method Im not sure how to use it since theese textfields is loaded if different repeaters.

*sigh* It would be so nice if I just could use Request.Form...

Answer (score 0):

Can you not loop through the children of the repeter

'lop from  0 to repeatername.items.count
  ' test data type for each item
     ' cast item as type textbox 
           ' use it

Comment: thanks for your reply but im not sure I follow... haven't been working with .NET in a while so sorry for being a bit slow..

How do u mean "test data type"?